# Downloading JSON file through Python

Tags: python, json, server, download, urllib

I have a link that gives me a "save as" dialog box for a .pst file every time I run it. 
I want to try to save the file to a 'sample.txt' file without opening it since the size is 500 MB.

Is there any way to get around this..?

```
import urllib

jsonl = urllib.request.urlopen("test.com/csv?date=2019-07-17")
```

I have tried the code above but it gives me

```
<http.client.HTTPResponse at 0x9ac4k10>
```

Comment: Well...  that's the response from server

Comment: Could you help me understand how I can interact with it? Im not sure where to start..

Comment: Check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html?highlight=httpresponse#httpresponse-objects) from the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I had a lot of trouble interacting with the site. I decided to just go with the webbrowser library.

```
import webbrowser
chrome_path="C:xxx\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
url = 'http://testsite/csv?date=2019-07-18'
```

Setting chrome to download files automatically populates my download folder from where i can automate everything else :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the data out of the object that urlopen returns.

Try

```
import urllib
with urllib.request.urlopen("test.com/csv?date=2019-07-17") as f:
        jsonl = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but nothing happened. It just took a minute to run but no output.